# how to set default value as a years in a field odoo 11?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-11, odoo-12

```py
fiscal_id = fields.Many2one('account.fiscalyear', 'Financial Year',default= '2020-2021')
```

I want default value as 2020-2021 in many2one field but i don't know how to assign the default value??

Answer (score 0):

you could use default `lambda` funtion as following:

```py
fiscal_id = fields.Many2one('account.fiscalyear', 'Financial Year', default=lambda self: self.env.ref('my_module.xml_id_related_to_the_record'))
```

in this case you need an `xml id` which will create the data record from xml file as following:

```xml
<odoo>
  <data>


    <record id="xml_id_related_to_the_record" model="account.fiscalyear">
      <field name="name">2020-2021</field>
    </record>


  </data>
</odoo>
```

please note that you may need to map the xml data correctly according to your model definition.

don't hesitate to let us know if it is working

Comment: Did you make sure that your xml file has been added to the `__manifest__.py` file. What is the error message you've got.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to search for the default record using the current date and return the corresponding record.

In the following example we return the first record found and set it as a default value for `fiscal_id` field.

```
@api.model
def _get_default_fiscalyear(self):
    return self.env['account.fiscalyear'].search([], limit=1)

fiscal_id = fields.Many2one('account.fiscalyear', 'Financial Year',default= _get_default_fiscalyear)
```